# I get Java.Net:bindException address already in use when attempting to start Jboss 5.1

Tags: jboss

I have a Jboss 5.1 server, and when I try to start it in debug mode I get adrees already in use. It doesn't matter what port I choose, the result is always the same. I tried passing -b 0.0.0.0 as an argument to the server and -Djboss.bind.address= my host to the JVM, but with no luck. Does anyone have any suggestion in regard? Thanks!

Comment: The *IP:port* is already in use. Another instance was already/still executing.

Comment: That's the thing, if I search with TCPView it only shows a single process executing on port 8080, if I kill it it stops my server, I don't think honestly any other process is listening on 8080